# bash: dpkg-reconfigure: command not found

Tags: debian, debian-buster

Debian10 seems to have removed the commands **poweroff**, **reboot** and **dpkg-reconfigure**, probably among others. What do I do instead of **dpkg-reconfigure locales**?

As a side note, I read the release notes and I think it's ridiculous this stuff isn't screamed at you when you read them.

```
# dpkg-reconfigure
bash: dpkg-reconfigure: command not found
```

edit: I am already aware I can get the dpkg-configure bin by installing a package: **debconf**. This package was not installed by default. This normally indicates deprecation.

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure is provided by the debconf package. You should just rry to install it: apt-get install debconf

Comment: why is it not installed by default?

Comment: It should be; it is on all Ubuntus anyway.

Comment: i just installed debian10 without graphical interface. Not there :/

Comment: Not too sure about Debian 10, but on 9 you get the same message when you don't have permission to run the command. Are you running as root already?
Could you try to run it again with `sudo`?

Comment: @fullmooninu Do you execute `dpkg-reconfigure` as `root`?

Comment: You can use update-alternatives as an alternative.

Comment: Why executing dpkg-reconfigure as root doesn't work but sudo dpkg-reconfigure works?

Comment: ok, now I know there is difference in PATH when you log in using 'su' and 'su -'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the wiki

https://wiki.debian.org/NewInBuster

Apparently I didn't read the other release notes

> Changes The su command in buster is provided by the util-linux source
>   package, instead of the shadow source package, and no longer alters
>   the PATH variable by default. This means that after doing su, your
>   PATH may not contain directories like /sbin, and many system
>   administration commands will fail. There are several workarounds:
>
> Use su - instead; this launches a login shell, which forces PATH to be
>   changed, but also changes everything else including the working
>   directory.
>
> Use sudo instead.  sudo still runs commands with an altered PATH
>   variable.
>
> Put ALWAYS_SET_PATH yes in /etc/login.defs to get an approximation of
>   the old behavior.
>
> Put the system administration directories (/sbin, /usr/sbin,
>   /usr/local/sbin) in your regular account's PATH (see
>   EnvironmentVariables for help with this).

thanks to my friend falso for making me use google more carefully

Answer (score 12):

This is the behaviour if you switched to root using `su` instead of `su -`, for example. In Debian 10 `dpkg-reconfigure` is located in `/usr/sbin/`, so it has to be in the `PATH`.

Compare these two `PATH`-variables:

```
user1@d10test:~$ su root
Password: 
root@d10test:/home/user1/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
root@d10test:/home/user1/# exit

user1@d10test:~$ su - root
Password: 
root@d10test:/home/user1/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

There you'll see that the environment set bei `su` does not include `sbin` in the `PATH`, so `dpkg-reconfigure` won't be found.

`debconf` *should* be installed by default, though.

Comment: this is probably it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Instead of

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

Debian 10 has not removed `dpkg-reconfigure` at all. It is present and part of the `debconf` package, which should have already been installed on your system. If it is missing from your system, then you need to install (or reinstall) the `debconf` package.

Comment: please read the edit

Comment: @fullmooninu Exactly how did you do the installation?

Comment: @fullmooninu - As this answer says, `debconf` should be installed by default. `apt-cache show debconf | grep Priority` returns `Priority: required`. Packages with priority "required" are installed by default and cannot be removed without getting the warning "You are about to do something potentially harmful. To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'". In the specific case of `debconf`, removing it would also remove 511 other dependent packages. If `debconf` is not installed on your system, then you (or someone) have not only removed it, but jumped through a few hoops to do so.

Comment: i just did a normal install, selected only ssh server and default applications and proceeded. It's a vm.

Answer (score 0):

Log as root using:

```
su - root
```

Instead of:

```
su
```

Comment: This helped me on debian 11 :)